# Find a first non NaN value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas dataframe such that

```
|user_id|value|No|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|id1|100|1|
|id1|200|2|
|id1|250|3|
|id2|NaN|1|
|id2|100|2|
|id3|400|1|
|id3|NaN|2|
|id3|200|3|
|id4|NaN|1|
|id4|NaN|2|
|id4|300|3|.
```

Then I want the folloing dataset:

```
|user_id|value|No|NewNo|
|:-:|:-:|:-:|:-:|
|id1|100|1|1|
|id1|200|2|2|
|id1|250|3|3|
|id2|100|2|1|
|id3|400|1|1|
|id3|NaN|2|2|
|id3|200|3|3|
|id4|300|3|1|
```

namely, I want to delete NaN values such that the first value of user_id is not NaN value. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

you can groupby & forward fill the value column. Null values in the transformed data indicate the values from the start for each group that are null. Filter out the rows that are null

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('user_id').value.ffill().apply(pd.notnull)].copy()
# application of copy here creates a new data frame and allows us to assign
# values to the result (df2). This is needed to create the column `NewNo` 
# in the next & final step
# df2 outputs:
   user_id  value  No
0    'id1'  100.0   1
1    'id1'  200.0   2
2    'id1'  250.0   3
4    'id2'  100.0   2
5    'id3'  400.0   1
6    'id3'    NaN   2
7    'id3'  200.0   3
10   'id4'  300.0   3
```

Generate `NewNo` column using ranking within the group.

```
df2['NewNo'] = df2.groupby('user_id').No.rank()

# df2 outputs:

   user_id  value  No  NewNo
0    'id1'  100.0   1    1.0
1    'id1'  200.0   2    2.0
2    'id1'  250.0   3    3.0
4    'id2'  100.0   2    1.0
5    'id3'  400.0   1    1.0
6    'id3'    NaN   2    2.0
7    'id3'  200.0   3    3.0
10   'id4'  300.0   3    1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`first_valid_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.first_valid_index.html) + [`cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

You can calculate indices for first non-null values by group, then use Boolean indexing:

```
# use transform to align groupwise first_valid_index with dataframe
firsts = df.groupby('user_id')['value'].transform(pd.Series.first_valid_index)

# apply Boolean filter
res = df[df.index >= firsts]

# use groupby + cumcount to add groupwise labels
res['NewNo'] = res.groupby('user_id').cumcount() + 1

print(res)

   user_id  value  No  NewNo
0      id1  100.0   1      1
1      id1  200.0   2      2
2      id1  250.0   3      3
4      id2  100.0   2      1
5      id3  400.0   1      1
6      id3    NaN   2      2
7      id3  200.0   3      3
10     id4  300.0   3      1
```